# I am trying to wrap my text around my images by floating the images to the left and right but nothing is happening

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-float

I am still learning and trying to get my text to wrap around two images, one left and one right, but nothing seems to be changing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong! :( Any suggestions are very appreciated!

Here is what it looks like.

[image]

```css
.skill-row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 2;
}

.layout-pic {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.phones-pic {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills">
  <h2>My Skills.</h2>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img class="circular" "layout-pic" src="images/layout.png" alt="website-layout-pic">

    <h3>Create Your Vision</h3>
    <p>I create using a complementary focus on color palettes, typography, and quality content. All of these elements help to bring your vision to life and really make it SHINE.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img class="circular" "phones-pic" src="images/seo.jpg" alt="phone-screens">

    <h3>Fine Tune Your Vision</h3>
    <p>As a developer, I know how to fine tune your website to give your audience the best functionality and visual appeal across devices.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Multi classes should be wrapped in one string like :

- `<img class="one two three"/>` ✔
- and not like `<img class="one" "two" "three"/>` this is wrong

Comment: Just spotted this, and was about to comment the same. This resolves the problem.

Comment: Oh wow, something so simple and it was driving me insane! lol - Thank you :)